# The SMTP host was not specified

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

i want to send mail to user when registered but error (The SMTP host was not specified) 
how to i configure smtp in web.config?

Comment: can you show your code that sends the email

Comment: <system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp from="automated@here.com" deliveryMethod ="Network">
<network defaultCredentials="true"   host="myMailserver.here.com"  port="25"  />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>

Comment: Take a look at this page on Scott Gu's blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should add following in web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="smtp.xxx.com" password="" userName=""/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: what is UserName? for example  I have an email info@site.com. [info] is UserName? or [info@site.com] ?

Comment: @AmirHossein No UserName and password are for using the SMTP server. This is often not required, but sometimes an SMTP server requires a UserName and Password.